# Yamaha YPG: 235 : shifting octaves

Tags: piano

I want to practice Beethovens moonlight sonata, but the sonata needs keys lower than what I have in my 76-keyboard. Is it possible to shift keys one octave down?

Comment: I'd love to download the manual from their website and tell you, but now Yamaha wants me to register to get any documents at all. Given that this functionality existed in Yamaha keyboards circa 1992, I can't imagine it's been taken out. It's probably buried in the menu somewhere; look for "8va" or "octave", or "shift", or "transpose".

Comment: Yes, there is a function in all Yamaha keyboards in this product line where you can transpose the keyboard by any interval you need. Consult your owners manual or write or call Yamaha's technical support staff.

Comment: I was searching for a way to lower the octaves of my Yamaha keyboard as well. What song was I trying to play? Moonlight Sonata. Great synchronicity.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, there is a function in all Yamaha keyboards in this product line where you can transpose the keyboard by any interval you need.

You should be able to [download the owners manual as a PDF at this link](http://download.yamaha.com/api/asset/file/?language=en&site=usa.yamaha.com&asset_id=35556).

The instructions say:

> 1) Press the Function button
>
> 2) Use the Category buttons to select the
>   Transpose item.
>
> 3) Use the dial to set the transpose value between -
>   12 and + 12 as required.

[image]

Comment: You can also change the main octave shift (e.g. up 2 octaves or down 1 octave). Instructions are on page 76 of the manual under voice functions. This might be easier and more convenient if you are just shifting by octaves.