# Transposing on a Yamaha PSR-180

Tags: keyboard, transposition

I'm new to the keyboard and music. Is it possible to transpose on the Yamaha PSR-180 so I can play Moonlight?

If it is, how do I do it?

Comment: Similar question: [Yamaha YPG: 235 : shifting octaves](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/12507/yamaha-ypg-235-shifting-octaves)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it seems that no, this instrument won't allow you to do this. I checked the manual on the Yamaha site, but there's no mention of any transposition facility.

Of course there's nothing to stop you transposing it yourself as you play - in fact transposing 'in your head' is a very useful skill and this may be a good opportunity to learn how to do it!